# How to add data toggle to link tag if ul is present in the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see the below code i have for my main menu on my website.

I want to add a data-toggle to the link tag for the dropdown but when the li doesnt contain ul I dont want the data-toggle added to the a tag. Would jquery be able to do this?

I am using bootstrap for this but in my menu I have menu links with no dropdown and the link url i add doesnt work as its expecting a dropdown to appear, if there a way around this?

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>`

Comment: Hey Paddy, what have you got so far? It sounds like you are trying to dynamically generate the `data-toggle` but you've only shown us some static HTML. Are you rendering things server side or client side? Is your HTML static? In general we need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers are correct, this is just another option using the `:has` selector. It's also a one-liner :)

```
$("ul.nav > li:has(ul) a").attr("data-toggle","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('UL').length === 0) {
        $(this).find('A').data('toggle', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better, any li inside the ul.nav that has a child ul will have data-toggle added.

```
$("ul.nav li ul").parent().attr("data-toggle","")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
$(function() {
    $(".dropdown:has(ul) a").attr("data-toggle", /*value here*/);
});
```